# How to make a table with a round arrow around the top left cell?

Tags: tables, arrows

Everything is in the question. The result would look like this (pardon my poor drawing skills):

[image: table]

Making a table is of course not the problem. If it can be easily made with a package, I would prefer to do so instead of making a solution in my preamble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option using Ti*k*Z and the `matrix` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm, outer sep=0pt}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
    {  & 0 & 1\\
     0 & 0 & 1\\
     1 & 0 & 0\\};
\draw[->, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm, looseness=1.2]
    (mymatrix-2-1.north west)to[out=90, in=180]node[below right=-3pt]{+}(mymatrix-1-2.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to put this in a macro, you must use `ampersand replacement`. There are a few ways to have the entries as parameters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newcommand{\mymatrix}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a/\b/\c/\d/\e/\f/\g/\h in {#2}
    \matrix (mymatrix) [matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm, outer sep=0pt}, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        ampersand replacement=\&
    ]
    {   \& \a \& \b\\
     \c \& \d \& \e\\
     \f \& \g \& \h\\};
\draw[->, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm, looseness=1.2]
    (mymatrix-2-1.north west)to[out=90, in=180]node[below right=-3pt]{#1}(mymatrix-1-2.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\mymatrix{+}{0/1/0/0/1/1/1/0}\qquad\mymatrix{$\times$}{0/1/0/0/0/1/0/1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly but I can't figure out how to make a command out of it. The parameters would be the symbol and the values inside the matrix. Maybe you could help?

Comment: @RomainBricout maybe a `\newenvironment` would be best instead of a command?

Comment: @JamesT I tried but I also need to have the symbol parameter and it didn't work anyways...

Comment: @RomainBricout I think you would be best of asking a new question, you can link to this one and ask how it could be converted into a command/environment, keeps this question and answer canonical

Comment: @RomainBricout: I updated my response.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccc}[hvlines,corners = NW]
    & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz [shorten > = 1pt, shorten <= 1pt]
  \draw [->] (2-|1) to [bend left = 45] node [below right,outer sep = -4pt] {$+$} (1-|2) ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]